# Creating Function for calculating prices with taxes

Tags: python

So I have a problem, that I have a block of code that works, but it works only when not used with Function.

The full story is, that I have to create a program that asks for the file ( which contains prices without taxes. For example 39, 15, 56, 19, 122, 31, 78 ). Then it asks the user to insert sales tax and then sum that is tax-free.

Code looks like this:

```
 filename = input("Please insert filename: ")
 salestax = int(input("Please insert % of sales tax: ")
 taxfree = int(input("Please insert sum of tax-free: ")

 file = open(filename)
 sum = 0
 for line in file:
     sum += float(line) * (1 + salestax/100)
 file.close()
 sum = round(sum, 2)
 print("Total with taxes " + str(sum))
```

But problem is that when I try to make the same block of code with Function, it won't work. It would not be a problem, but one criteria is that there must be used a Function to calculate taxes.

And one more thing. How could I sum up numbers with added sales taxes that are bigger than inserted tax-free? For example, the file contains prices: 6, 17, 79, 200, 54, 36. And inserted tax-free is 35. Then I add sales taxes to them and I need to get back sum with only prices that are bigger than inserted tax-free number.

I used IF statement and >= taxfree, but it still gave me total sum with also smaller numbers or 0 - nothing in between

Comment: Please show us your attempt that didn't work as well.

Comment: do you convert `salestax` and `taxfree` to floats also?

Answer (score 0):

So I got it and thought I post the answer here too :

```
def price_withTax(price_withoutTax, percent):
    return float(price_withoutTax) * (1+percent/100)

filename = input("Please insert filename: ")
salestax = int(input("Please insert % of sales tax: ")
taxfree = int(input("Please insert sum of tax-free: ")

sum = [] 
file = open(filename)
for line in file:
    sum += [price_withTax(line, salestax)]
file.close()

total = 0
totalWithTax = 0
for line in sum:
    total += line
    if line >= taxfree:
       totalWithTax += line

tax = totalWithTax - totalWithTax/(1 + salestax/100)

total = round(total, 2)
tax = round(tax, 2)

print(“Total with taxes “ + str(total))
```